# Unquote splice equivalent in Scheme Hygienic Macros

Tags: macros, scheme, r5rs

I have Scheme implementation and right now I'm testing Hygienic macros. I have macro `-->` that work like this:

```
(--> document (querySelector "body"))
```

that will just call JavaScript

```
document.querySelector("body")
```

and I want to create macro that will create macro that will call methods on objects. So If I use:

```
(define-method document querySelector)
```

it will create function:

```
(define-macro (querySelector . args)
  `(--> document (querySelector ,@args))
```

This is easy in Lisp macros because I have ,@ to splice the args. Example:

```
(define-macro (define-method object method)
   (let ((args (gensym)))
    `(define-macro (,method . ,args)
        `(--> ,',object (,',method ,@,args)))))
```

This can be tested with [my Scheme Interpreter on Codepen](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/GxgWBq).

Below is simple macro in CommonLisp that generate macros that display text (my testing macro in Clisp)

```
(define-macro (make-printer name)
  `(define-macro (,name)
      `(let ((,',name "xxx"))
          (write ,',name))))
```

this is just example of `,',` usage that I was testing. It create useless macro that print "xxx".

I thought that to solve this I need to create a macro that will create macro.

```
(define-syntax define-method
   (syntax-rules ()
     ((_ obj method)
      (define-syntax method
          (syntax-rules ()
             ???)))))
```

The problem is that I can create function because I can't use apply to call method on object It need to be a function call. I also can't modify `-->` macro to allow using apply because someone may want to call method apply on object like

```
(--> fn (apply null '(1 2 3))
```

Working example:

```
(--> display (apply (current-environment) '#((1 2 3))))
```

it's calling `Function.prototype.apply` with environment and array/vector of single element list. Same as `(display '(1 2 3))`

To make it 100% Scheme issue, I can think of this case I have macro that accept variable number of arguments and I want to create macro that will create wrapper for that macro.

E.g: I have macro `(foo name . args)`  and I want to create macro make-foo that will create macros that call foo. (make-foo get-name) should create macro `(get-name . args)` that will expand into `(foo 'get-name . args)`. And foo can be defined like:

```
(define-syntax foo
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ args ...)
      (display '(args ...)))))


(define-syntax make-foo
   (syntax-rules ()
     ((_ name)
      (define-syntax name
          (syntax-rules ()
             ((_ args ...)
              (foo name args ...)))))))

(make-foo hello)
(hello 1 2 3)
```

What about if I want to create Scheme Hygienic macro where name is `foo-hello` if I pass `hello`. Is something like this possible with `syntax-rules`? Or do I need to use lisp macros or syntax-case. I prefer if possible to have R5RS code.

I was also trying this to be able to create function that have variable number of arguments and create macro that will generate function with same args:

```
(define (bar . args)
  (for-each display args))

(define-syntax caller
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ method)
       (define (method . args)
          (bar . args)))))

(caller foo)
(foo 1 2 3)
```

but this don't work, tested in Kawa an Guile.

Comment: One thing that might help you with handling ellipses in macro-defining macros is either "ellipsis quoting" or "custom ellipsis". I'm not sure whether either of those are in R5RS, but I know ellipsis quoting is in R7RS and Kawa, and custom ellipses are in Kawa and Guile. Ellipsis quoting is `(... <template>)`, and custom ellipsis is `(syntax-rules ddd () <cases>)`. Often one of these is necessary for macro-defining macros where the inner macro being generated uses ellipses

Comment: @AlexKnauth they are in [SRFI 46](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-46/srfi-46.html), but my question is mainly about splice and not macros-defining macros. Also my macros that define macros don't use ellipsis.

Comment: @AlexKnauth You was right, I was able to create my macro defining macro in Guile, with ellipsis alias.